# Update table after insert a new row to database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'll try to be as clear as I can. I'm trying to code a CRUD. I have a table that shows all the info about products. To register a new item I have a form in a modal and it sends the data with AJAX to a .php file called 'registro.php' where the data is inserted into the MySQL table.

I'd like to make that after clicking the 'Submit' button of the new-item form, the table auto-realoaded showing the new row too without refreshing the page.

The INSERT INTO is working fine but after inserting a new item, the `<table>` that displays all the data just **disappears**

So, this is my form @ **index.php**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 <span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Registrar un artículo </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
             <!-- Modal form -->
                <form name="nuevo_registro" id="nuevo_registro" action="" onsubmit="registrarNew(); return false">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción del artículo"/>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">Bs.</span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio"/>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="existencia">Existencia</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="existencia" name="existencia" placeholder="Unidades en existencia"/>
                   </div>
                   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitmodal" class="btn btn-default">Guardar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the ajax code at the bottom of **index.php**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#nuevo_registro').submit(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
   url: 'registro.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: $(this).serialize()
  })
  .done(function(data){
   $('#myModalNorm').modal('toggle');
   $('#lista_articulos').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#lista_articulos').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
   });
  })
  .fail(function(){
   alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
  });
 });
});
```

And this is **registro.php** where the data is inserted into the MySQL table

```html
<?php
if ( $_POST ) {

require_once 'dbconnection.php';

$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
$precio=$_POST['precio'];
$existencia=$_POST['existencia'];

$query = "INSERT INTO producto (descripcion, precio, existencia, estado) VALUES ('$descripcion', '$precio', '$existencia', 'A')";
$conexion->query($query);
$conexion->close();
}
?>
```

Hope you can help me and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do that, one day, and here's my solution:

1. Send data to PHP file and INSERT to the mysql database
2. Get the last inserted ID, find all available data regarding that row
3. Make an array out of that data and json_encode it
4. On the main page with the table, find the table and prepend or append the data you just received.

Comment: You should consider including code examples, this will make your answer more useful. Also, consider reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Welcome to SO.

Comment: Your step-by-step answer gave me the orientation I needed to solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @bramcastillo No problem! Always happy to help! :)

Comment: @alex_milhouse Thanks for the reference! Duly noted!